# ERROR: "4.9E-324" is out of range for type double precision

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-8.4

I saw this error when trying to perform the following insert into a PostgreSQL 8.4.20:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 12 insert into perf_raw_2017_03_16 values ('3129', '182', '818', '2017-03-20 16:01:17.507000 +00:00:00', '4.9E-324') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: "4.9E-324" is out of range for type double precision
```

However, when I try the same insert on a different machine with PostgreSQL 8.4.4, the insert finishes fine. When I do a select to verify that the value is there, it also finishes fine:

```
select * from perf_raw_2017_03_20 where guid_key=3129 and property_key=182;

 guid_key | property_key | instance_id_key |       time_stamp        |         value
----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------
     3129 |          182 |             818 | 2017-03-20 16:01:17.507 | 4.94065645841247e-324
```

The type of the column is `double precision`, which, according to the documentation, is "15 decimal digits precision". The error makes sense, I am indeed outside of its range, so I am not very surprised by the error. Here are my questions though:

**The binary format of the DB does not change with minor releases. Why did this even work in 8.4.4 and not 8.4.20?**

I did not find anything in the changelog that would explain this:
https://bucardo.org/postgres_all_versions.html

**Why does the DB still allow me to insert the value if I use a select to get it from an existing record?**

I will probably post an answer to this question based on what I observed, but it would be cool if somebody could provide a deeper insight into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for software that was EOL in July 2014. It's far from supported. I'm not sure I trust git on those releases. The work transferring over the repo may have been sloppy. You may have to go back to SVN to get an authoritative answer but [this seems to be responsible](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/c318aeed84438619fc6b8c647def1730a110f04b)...

> On some platforms, strtod() reports ERANGE for a denormalized value (ie,
>   one that can be represented as distinct from zero, but is too small to have
>   full precision).  On others, it doesn't.  It seems better to try to accept
>   these values consistently, so add a test to see if the result value
>   indicates a true out-of-range condition.  This should be okay per Single
>   Unix Spec.  On machines where the underlying math isn't IEEE standard, the
>   behavior for such small numbers may not be very consistent, but then it
>   wouldn't be anyway.
>
> Marti Raudsepp, after a proposal by Jeroen Vermeulen

You can see the thread about [this here.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTi%3DZ6cT8c_j6YrXHcx%3DCkrxUMt6NBw%40mail.gmail.com)

Comment: @JohnEye the methodology to find this, if interested, is to find what triggers the error which was a one minute job with the error you produced, and to use git blame through the github user interface. In the event you want to know how I did it. There was a few commits that changed the white space on this code, I kept blaming-back until I found this commit in the date range applicable to 8.4

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. Apparently, I shouldn't have given up on the github search, most of the time it works so badly that I just search using a generic web search engine.